# hibernate - Postgres- target lists can have at most 1664 entries

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, orm

We are using hibernate, postgres 8.3x

Our entities are many to one mapped with eager fetching.
We have multiple associations with Many to one mapping.

As we added new columns to any other existing entities,
We are getting below error:

**target lists can have at most 1664 entries**

I searched internet and they say this is due to 
More number of select statements in sql query (generated by hibernate)

Can you any body please let us know if there is any configuration (in postgres)
to update max number columns in configuration or any other solution to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to convince me that such a great number of columns is needed. Even with the joins, this should be at least 400-500 columns per table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="25"/>
```

Comment: https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2201965&sid=854c31535f1f18df45608641421f469c

Comment: Sorry Martin. This is not correct. If we increase the max fetch depth, more number of columns will be included in the fetch list and it will throw error.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes this happen when there are too much @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) in the project.
So, when is not necessary the FetchType.EAGER, put @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

This help me, try!

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is definitely something **wrong** with your model/mappings/query. The right way to fix that is to work on your model/mappings/query, not on the max number of columns in PostgreSQL (I don't even get how you reached it, a query that retrieve 1664+ columns doesn't make any sense).

Comment: The error says entries, not columns. You can do it with a really big WHERE ID IN VALUES (?,?,...) query. as opposed to WHERE ID IN (...)

Answer (score 1):

This is the max number of columns in PostgreSQL, that's correct. But why do you need even more columns? Just do some normalization and your problem is gone. Or don't use a relational database at all, you will always hit the max number of columns when you don't normalize.

Comment: Thanks Frank Heikens.
It is not about the number of columns in a single database table. But when we join multiple columns (by createCriteria in hibernate) we are getting this error.

Comment: Hmmm, I see, now I get it. Can't help you there, we never had this problem, never had so much columns in our queries.