# jpa and postgres delete : 'ERROR: number of columns (1703) exceeds limit (1664)' & fails

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-mapping

We are using the JPA (hibernate) and Postgres,

One of the delete operation is throwing the error 'ERROR: number of columns (1703) exceeds limit (1664)'

The delete method is as shown below and we pass clazz object as parent of all the entities.

```
 protected <E extends T> E delete(UUID id, Class<E> clazz) {
    log.debug("deleting entity {}", id);
    E object = getEntityManager().find(clazz, id); //clazz is parent of all the entities
    if (object != null){
        getEntityManager().remove(object);
    }
    return object;
}
```

Please advice

there is question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417972/hibernate-postgres-target-lists-can-have-at-most-1664-entries) similar to this, but has no specific answer ?

Thanks

Comment: if some SQL statement throws an exception then don't you think it would be nice to show the SQL statement? (will be present in the log). Also the stack trace will say what is called, hence what it is doing

Comment: I have SQL statement which is very large,  I am sorry for some reasons I can't post entire sql query.

Comment: I assume the exception is thrown when calling `find()` because of a lot of eager relations. As a workaround, try with `getReference()` instead of `find()`, like this `E object = getEntityManager().getReference(clazz, id);`

Comment: Seems like the PostgreSQL dialect in Hibernate should be smart enough to handle this, but I guess it isn't.

Comment: Maybe possible workaround it to use `delete` query if cascading isn't needed?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the `em.find` can cause a lot a problems with multiple joins he does, even with no eagers relations. Try to pass the object you want to manipulate to the `getEntityManager()` directly and not just the id. Something like this:

```
   protected <E extends T> E delete(Object object, Class<E> clazz) {
      log.debug("deleting entity {}", object.getId());         
      if (object != null){
         getEntityManager().remove(object);
      }
      return object;
   }
```

EDIT:

More information about cascades: When you have too much cascadetype.ALL in your associations, every column in every table do you have in the mapping the hibernate will join and eventually will throw this error.

For example, i have a entity with no eagers, every associated table is fetch type lazy, but with lot of cascades.

The time i call the `getEntityManager().merge(entity)`, i was getting this error. I have some table with 80 and 100 columns, maybe not the best normalization, but still acceptable, what i did was remove the cascadetype.MERGE where was not needed and voilà.